# Genymotion emulator shows blank white space as shown in screenshot

Tags: android

I have followed all the steps and at last when I run the Google Nexus 5-5.1 .0 emulator it shows blank white space as shown in screenshot same with Moto X-4.4.4

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Your question needs more details. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example and see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question.

Comment: In the screenshot you posted there is a error message which says: "phone not available in the personal use version. For more information click the icon." Did you clicked the icon ? If yes what additional information did you get from that ?

Comment: After clicking on that icon phone tab is open which is also blank as shown in screen shot.

Comment: Please reply...I need help..

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on that icon phone tab is open which is also blank as shown in screen shot.

[Blank phone tab after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kcSm.png)